# CR2008 Suppressed SubReport's parameters are showing on main report

Tags: crystal-reports, parameter-passing, crystal-reports-2008, subreport

I am a very new user to crystal and have taken over a project that someone else has done and left.

Here is my current issue. I have a Main report that has a ton of sub reports on it. There is one sub-report that is suppressed that is causing a parameter prompt on the main report. I have looked through documentation about the links from main to sub but there is no link between these sub-report parameters and the main report. Also the sub report uses these parameters in the report itself. IE start date - end date are the parameters and are used on the sub report so I can't just remove them. How can I stop the prompt for these two parameters from the sub-report in the main report?

Thanks a Ton.

Comment: So trying some further things to satisfy the parameter from the sub report to see if that would keep it from showing when running the main report. I have created a parameter on the main report called start and linked this with the sub report parameter start. In the main report saved data selection I used the following code {?Start} = CurrentDate. This does not seem to be pushing the current date to the sub report and keeping the prompt from showing for that parameter. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: what about other sub reports? are those have parameters? if yes are they showing up?

Comment: Siva other reports do have parameters that are getting passed from the main report. The difference is the parameters on the other reports are not used directly on their report. To fully answer your question no these other reports are not showing up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new report and just did not include the sub report mentioned. Thanks.